# Nginx load balancer sticky ip_hash

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm trying to create stickiness in nginx load balancer using a exsiting cookie `internal_ip` that I've created on my python app.
I'm using the ip_hash method becuase I don't have nginx plus.
I'm new on this, and I get this error:

> 2023/04/30 16:41:26 [emerg] 1#1: invalid number of arguments in "ip_hash" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:7
> nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "ip_hash" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:7

So I don't understand what's worng and where is my error?

```
events {
worker_connections 1000;
}

http {
    upstream app {
        ip_hash $cookie_internal_ip consistent;
        server 172.18.0.3:5000;
        server 172.18.0.4:5000;
        server 172.18.0.5:5000;
    }

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        add_header Set-Cookie "internal_ip=$remote_addr";
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm newbie at nginx too but

1. based on [`ip_hash`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#ip_hash) docs it must be only `ip_hash;` directive without any params.
2. Maybe you mean [`hash`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#hash)?

```
events {
worker_connections 1000;
}

http {
    upstream app {
        # if you need simply ip sticky load balancing
        ip_hash;
        # if you need hash by key-value sticky load balancing
        hash $cookie_internal_ip consistent;
        server 172.18.0.3:5000;
        server 172.18.0.4:5000;
        server 172.18.0.5:5000;
    }

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        add_header Set-Cookie "internal_ip=$remote_addr";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, I've read that without the `ip_hash` directive, the load balancing won't be sticky.  So how can I use my cookie with ip_hash? or just use `hash` like what you wrote and it will do the work and be sticky too?

Comment: As I said, I'm a newbie too, following official docs [link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#hash) (you can click on it to read) "Specifies a load balancing method for a server group where the client-server mapping is based on the hashed key value" which looks like sticky based on "key-value" custom param, but I think the best way is to just simply test it